# how can i create a geometrical progress program multiple of 10

Tags: python, yield

I want to write a program in Python 3 that includes a myprice function which returns X values that geometrically progress starting from 1.. I want the value of X which is the number of values to be 3 and the geometrical progress to be 10.. so that my program will print(1,10,100).

How can I do this?

thanks in advance.. Nantia

```
def myprice(X,geometrical progress):
    i=0
    i += 1 
    while i < X:
        i =

        yield i

for i in my price(3,10):
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@techUser. You can write something like the following:

```
def myprice(x, geometrical_factor=10):
    """
    A generator of a geometrical progression. The default factor is 10.

    The initial term is 'start = 1';

    Parameter:
    x : int
      number of terms to generate
    geometrical_factor: int
      geometrical factor [default: 10]
    """
    start = 1

    i = 0 # Geometrical term counter
    while i < xterm:
        if i == 0:
            yield start
        else:
            start = start * geometrical_factor
            yield start
        i += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on solution by @eapetcho,

```
def myprice(x, fctr=10):
    """A generator of a geometrical progression. The default factor is 10.

    The initial term is 1.

    Args:
        x   (int): number of terms to generate
        ftr (int): geometrical factor. Default is 10

    """

    start = 1

    i = 0
    while i < x:
        if i == 0:
            yield start
        else:
            start = start * fctr
            yield start
        i += 1

for n in myprice(20, 2):
  print(n)
```

Output

```
1
2
4
8
16
32
64
128
256
512
1024
2048
4096
8192
16384
32768
65536
131072
262144
524288
```